# Use jQuery to ignore form submit when clicking an input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with a submit input and I need that when the button gets clicked, my script do some Ajax actions. Also I need to disable that button during the Ajax request. So I need a jQuery command to avoid real form submit when input is clicked. I tried to use this:

```
$('input.searchplease').click(function () {
    $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');

    alert('Yep');
    //Do Ajax
});
```

This didn't worked. I mean, the alert shown correctly but form is submitted. So what is your suggestion?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('input.searchplease').click(function (e) {
   $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');

   alert('Yep');
   //Do Ajax

   e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input.searchplease').click(function () {
    alert('yep');
    return false;
});
```

This should work

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    ... ajax things

    return false;
});
```

I would rather not disable the button (and then enable it), unless I have to.

Comment: you forgot to disable the submit button

Comment: i meant the actual button, see the OP's question :)

Comment: @Joseph. I read it, he just want to disable the submit, not the button.

Answer (score 0):

try this way :

```
$("#id-of-your-form").submit(function() {

    $("#id-of-your-submit-input").attr("disabled", true);

    // do-ajax
    // you can use jquery's ajax complete handler to enable the submit button again

    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do the trick:

```
$('form').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#submit-button-ID').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $.ajax({
        ...,
        success: function() {
                $('#submit-button-ID').removeAttr('disabled');
              }
    });
});
```